# вывод изображения из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-сервер

Нужно вывести изображение, хранящееся в базе данных (использую *wamserver*).

В базу оно сохраняется, даже можно скачать, при этом формат у него `images-image_data.bin`, но не выводится.

Если поменять:

```
header('Content-type: '. $image['mime_type']);
```

на:

```
header('Content-type: image/*');
```

то браузер предложит мне скачать мой файл `showImages.php`.

Если совсем закомментировать `header`, то на экран выведется куча символов (я так понимаю, что это и есть мое изображение).

Что мне следует поменять в коде для того, чтобы изображение отобразилось в браузере?

вот код:

**index.html - форма регистрации**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Форма регистрации</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="content" action="regUser.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="entryField">
            <label for="firsName">Ваше имя:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name">
        </div>

        <div class="entryField">
            <label for="SecondName">Ваша фамалия:</label>
            <input type="text" name="second_name">
        </div>

        <div class="entryField">
            <label for="pass">Пароль:</label>
            <input type="text" name="pass">
        </div>

        <div class="entryField">
            <label for="email">Емаил</label>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </div>

        <div class="entryField">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000">
            <label for="userPic">Аватар</label>
            <input type="file" name="userPic" size="30">
        </div>

        <div class="entryField">
            <label for="bio">Биография</label>
            <textarea name="bio" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="entryField">
            <input type="submit" value="Регистрация">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**regUser.php - обработка отправленных данных**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>обработка данных</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        //подключение к БД
        require_once 'connectBD.php';

        ($_REQUEST) or
            handle_error("вы не ввели данные", mysql_error());

        $first_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
        $second_name = $_REQUEST['second_name'];
        $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
        $bio = $_REQUEST['bio'];
        $img_file_name = "userPic";

        //потенциальные ошибки отправки файла
        $php_errors = array(1 => 'Превышен максимальный размер файла',2 => 'превышен максимальный размер файла в HTML', 3 => 'Была отправлена только часть файла', 4 => 'Файл для отправки не был выбран');

        //проверка отсутствия ошибок при отправки изображения
        ($_FILES[$img_file_name]['error'] == 0)
            or handle_error("сервер не может получить выбранное изображение",$php_errors[$_FILES[$img_file_name]['error']]);

        //проверка формата файла
        @getimagesize($_FILES[$img_file_name]['tmp_name'])
            or handle_error("файл не является изображением","функция сработала");   

        //вставка изображения в таблицу
        $image = $_FILES[$img_file_name];
        $image_filename = $image['name'];
        $image_info = getimagesize($image['tmp_name']);
        $image_mime_type = $image_info['mime'];
        $image_size = $image['size'];
        $image_data = file_get_contents($image['tmp_name']);

        $insert_image_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO images (filename, mime_type, file_size, image_data) VALUES ('%s','%s',%d,'%s');",
                            mysql_real_escape_string($image_filename),
                            mysql_real_escape_string($image_mime_type),
                            mysql_real_escape_string($image_size),
                            mysql_real_escape_string($image_data));

        mysql_query($insert_image_sql) or
            handle_error("ошибка загрузки изображения",mysql_error());

        $insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, pass, email, bio, profile_pic_id) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s',%d);",
                            mysql_real_escape_string($first_name),
                            mysql_real_escape_string($second_name),
                            mysql_real_escape_string($pass),
                            mysql_real_escape_string($email),
                            mysql_real_escape_string($bio),
                            mysql_insert_id());

        mysql_query($insert_sql) or
            handle_error("ошибка записи пользователя",mysql_error());

        // перенаправление пользователя на страницу профиля
        header("Location: showUsers.php?user_id=". mysql_insert_id());
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**showImage.php - отдельная страница для получения изображения**

```
       <?php
    // подключение БД
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or 
            handle_error("Ошибка подключения к базе данных",mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("testBd") or
            handle_error("Ошибка выбора базы данных",mysql_error());


                if(!isset($_REQUEST['image_id'])) {
                    handle_error("не указано изображения для загрузки.","");
                }

                $image_id = $_REQUEST['image_id'];

                $select_query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = %d",$image_id);
                $result = mysql_query($select_query);

                if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                    handle_error("не удалось найти изображение", "изображение с ID {$image_id} не найдено");
                }

                $image = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                //загрузка изображения
                header('Content-type: '. $image['mime_type']);
                header('Content-length: ' . $image['file_size']);
                echo $image['image_data'];

            ?>
```

**showUsers.php - вывод данных**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Ваш профиль</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    //подключение к БД
    require_once 'connectBD.php';

    if(!isset($_REQUEST['user_id'])) {
            handle_error("не указан пользователь.","");
        }

    $userId = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $select_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = " . $userId;
    //mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); принудительно меняем кодировку
    $result = mysql_query($select_user);

    if ($result) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $second_name = $row['last_name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $bio = $row['bio'];
        $image_id = $row['profile_pic_id'];

    }   else {
        handle_error("возникла ошибка с поиском вашей информации","ползователь с ID {$userId} не найден");
    }

    ?>
    <h1>Добро пожаловать <?php echo "{$first_name}"; ?></h1>    
    <div class="content">
        <h2>профиль</h2>
        <p class="leftCont borderBot"><?php echo "{$first_name} {$second_name}"; ?></p>
        <div class="clear leftCont">
            <img src="showImage.php?image_id=<?php echo $image_id; ?>" alt="фото">
            <p class="bio leftCont"><?php echo "{$bio}"; ?></p>
        </div>
        <p class="leftCont">связаться с пользователем:</p>
        <ul><li><?php echo "{$email}"; ?></li></ul>
        <a class="buttonBack" href="index.html">Назад</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**База данных**
таблица images
[image: таблица images]

таблица users
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой `mime_type` у изображений в базе?

Answer (score 1):

в заголовке желательно указывать [**правильный** формат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2#image): `Content-type: image/формат`.

ориентируйтесь на пример из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7793098/4827341).

---

**обновление**

а ошибка — в способе обращения к элементам массива.

вы получаете **обыкновенный** массив:

```
$image = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

а дальше обращаетесь к его элементам не по номерам, а по именам, как к элементам **ассоциативного** массива:

```
$image['mime_type']
$image['file_size']
$image['image_data']
```

для такого обращения нужно создавать **ассоциативный** массив с помощью функции [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: а в чем разница? у меня переменной `$image` присваивается массив и потом выводится конкретное значение `echo $image['image_data'];`
по поводу той статьи сделал все один в один, результат такой же значит проблема не в этом.. может как то криво файл записывается?

Comment: @Алексей, прошу прощения, проглядел. но про `content-type` — всё ещё актуально.

Comment: в базе mime_type формат "image/jpeg", да и как уже сказал смена с
header('Content-type: '. $image['mime_type']); на header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); не помогает

Comment: 1. ошибки в логах сервера не появляются? 2. в браузере при обращении к `showimage.php` (с необходимыми параметрами) отображается изображение?

Comment: если изображение не отображается, приложите к вопросу выдачу команды `wget -S --spider http://ваш.сервер/showimage.php?необходимые.параметры`.

Comment: 1. Warning:  Illegal string offset 'image_data' in D:\WEB\wamp\www\myproject\lesson4\showImage.php on line 29
2. не отображается(пробвал разными браузерами)
3. [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3uFjaXhBunmcTNUSDNTVDdkWms/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Алексей, теперь понятно. смотрите обновление ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, но проблему это не решило :)
Вообщем мне все это надоело и я решил поставить старый добрый **denwer** вместо **wampserver** и о чудо все заработало. Не знаю что конкретно не нравилось **wamp**(может из за того что там используется более новая версия php).
ps на странице **reqUsers.php** я случайно воткнул html блоки, на что denwer заругался т.к. на этой же странице используется **header()**, а wamp как то этот момент пропустил(да и я тоже).
Еще раз спасибо что помогали мне!